# ArrayType of mixed data in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I want to merge two different array list into one. Each of the array is a column in spark dataframe. Therefore, I want to use a udf

```
def some_function(u,v):
  li = list()
  for x,y in zip(u,v):
      li.append(x.extend(y))
  return li

udf_object = udf(some_function,ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType()))))
new_x = x.withColumn('new_name',udf_object(col('name'),col('features')))
```

This is the schema of data:

```
root
 |-- blockingkey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- blocked_records: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- flattened_array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am trying to merge name and features. so it is like the first element in name will be merged with first element in features. 
But this only returns an array with NUll values when there is Integer or FloatValues. Kindly help me resolve this issue if this can be done using udf or other wise.

Comment: you can't have float and string merged into an array both should be of same type

Comment: If I just append x in li, then it return me correctly only names. But I want the list extended by y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `dataframe` and `schema` as

```
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|features                                        |name                                    |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(3.0, 5.0)]|[WrappedArray(a, b), WrappedArray(c, d)]|
|[WrappedArray(2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(3.0, 5.0)]|[WrappedArray(a, b), WrappedArray(c, d)]|
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+

root
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Then you can define the `udf` function and call the `udf` function as

```
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def some_function(u,v):
    li = []
    for x, y in zip(u, v):
        li.append(x + y)
    return li

udf_object = f.udf(some_function,t.ArrayType(t.ArrayType(t.StringType())))

new_x = x.withColumn('new_name',udf_object(f.col('name'),f.col('features')))
```

so `new_x` would be

```
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                        |name                                    |new_name                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(3.0, 5.0)]|[WrappedArray(a, b), WrappedArray(c, d)]|[WrappedArray(a, b, 2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(c, d, 3.0, 5.0)]|
|[WrappedArray(2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(3.0, 5.0)]|[WrappedArray(a, b), WrappedArray(c, d)]|[WrappedArray(a, b, 2.0, 3.0), WrappedArray(c, d, 3.0, 5.0)]|
+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- new_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful